# How to develop with C# for Symbol MT2070 using old SDK / EMDK?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, motorola

I am (re)developing a web application that needs to interact with a mobile scanner. My client currently has several Motorola / Symbol MT2070 scanners. The software running on those scanners was written in C# using the [Symbol EMDK for .Net](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=97036&productDetailGUID=0552d085364cf310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD). I am having problems getting a working development environment (I don't usually develop in C#).

I am running Windows 8.1 and using Visual Studio 2015 CE. But when I try to install the EMDK the installer fails saying it cannot find Visual Studio. The EMDK description says it needs Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 but I cannot find or buy those because VS 2015 is out.

The MT2070 scanner runs Windows CE 5.0 and uses the .Net 2.0 Compact Framework.

How can I develop software for this scanner using a modern toolchain? Is there any way to force installation of the EMDK? Any way to get the Symbol.MT2000 C# CILs another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that Zebra acquire Motorola Solutions Enterprise Business in Oct. 2014.*

Latest version of Zebra's EMDK for .NET support MT2070:

- [EMDK for .NET
  v2.9](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=97036&productDetailGUID=0552d085364cf310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD)

The EMDK works only with Visual Studio 2005 SP1 and Visual Studio 2008 because these are the compilers that supports Windows CE/Windows Mobile. Newer compilers doesn't support these operative systems. So, to develop for a Windows CE v5.0 machine you can only use VS2005 SP1 or VS2008.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. and the only way to get these old versions seems to be having an MSDN subscription.